# SPUtility.SendEmail doesn't exist

Tags: 2013, email, sputility

I'm trying to send an email with sharepoint's `SPUtility.SendEmail()` method, but according to Visual studio it doesn't exist. I have `using Microsoft.Sharepoint` and `.Utilities` included, but still nothing.

Am I missing an assembly or something? I'm on Sharepoint 2013 in .NET 4.5

Code below. Visual studio doesn't show any suggestions when I type SendEmail for any overloads.

```
var web = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPUtility.SendEmail(web, false,false,"blank@blank.com","subject","message");
```

Comment: Are you using a Sandbox solution?

Comment: Show your code.  Which overload are you using?

Comment: I am using a sandbox solution i believe. No overloads are available, see edit.

Comment: Did you get runtime or compile time exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SPUtility.SendEmail()` is not available in a sandbox solution.

You can use the SendEmail activity in a SharePoint Designer Workflow to accomplish your task.

Comment: I created a new project as a farm solution and it is now detecting the method. Hopefully I will be able to get this working. I wish they would've said something about that on the MSDN page for this method. Thank you!